problem with sending the correct response from tools to the azure open ai model (python)
I'm creating an application for learning and fun that uses functions, I have weather data (from a course on Udemy) and I'm adding a new function that is to ask the user for credentials based on certain questions, and retrieve their data from the database.
So I create a string of messages in the messages list starting with system, and then adding user and assistant
messages = [
{
    "role": "system",
    "content": (
        "You are an assistant and you help answer questions only in Polish: "
        "If the user asks about their personal data (e.g., provide my email, age, address, or account status, etc.), use the 'logowanie' function unless the requested information has already been retrieved by this function in the message. "
        "If the user asks about the weather in a specific location, you respond using the getWeather function. "
        "For legal questions, you respond using Azure Search and the ustawa123 index. "
    )
}]

prompt = input("Ask about something or write exit to end: ")
while prompt != "exit":
    messages.append({"role":"user", "content":prompt+" (answer only in polish)"})
   
    response = get_response(messages)

My get_response function look like this:
def get_response(messages):
tools = [
    {
        "type": "function",
        "function": {
            "name": "getWeather",
            "description": "Get real-time weather information/data for a specific location/place",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "location": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "the exact location for which the current weather is to be determined",
                    },
                },
                "required": ["location"]
            },
        }
    },
        {
        "type": "function",
        "function": {
            "name": "logowanie",
            "description": "If a user asks for their personal information (e.g. my email, age, account balance, and other data that the model normally does not have access to), use this function",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {},                   
            },
        }
    }
]


response = client.chat.completions.create(
model = "4pl1",
messages = messages ,    
max_tokens=800,
temperature=0.4,
top_p=0.7,
frequency_penalty=0,
presence_penalty=0,
extra_body={
    "data_sources":[
        {
            "type": "azure_search",
            "parameters": {
                "endpoint": "xxx",
                "index_name": "ustawa123",                    
                "in_scope": False,
                "authentication": {
                    "type": "api_key",
                    "key": "xxx",
                }
            }
        }
    ],
}, 
tools=tools,
tool_choice="auto"      
)
return response

And now when the function is called, I want to add the information about the function call to messages first and then the information from tool
   if hasattr(response.choices[0].message, 'tool_calls') and response.choices[0].message.tool_calls is not None :
    function_name = response.choices[0].message.tool_calls[0].function.name 
    call_id = response.choices[0].message.tool_calls[0].id 
    function_argument = json.loads(response.choices[0].message.tool_calls[0].function.arguments)
    messages.append({
        "role": "assistant",
        "content": None,  
        "tool_calls": {
            "tool_call_id": call_id,
            "functions":{"name": function_name,
                        "arguments": json.dumps(function_argument),
                        "type": "function"  }
            
            }
    })

But this gives me error:
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'requestid': 'b3356dff-7a7d-4c3a-a047-ce3fbcf16de9', 'code': 400, 'message': 'Validation error at #/messages/3/name: Extra inputs are not permitted'}}

I'm trying to add the tool according to the Microsoft documentation
 messages.append({
                "tool_call_id": call_id,
                "role": "tool",
                "name": function_name,
                "content": function_response,
            })

But here it also always shouts that the name shouldn't be here and when I delete it, the model doesn't notice that it already has answers.
I am using the latest openai library and have tried several api versions, today I have set:
client = AzureOpenAI(
api_key = "xxx",
api_version = "2024-05-01-preview",# "2023-07-01-preview" "2024-02-01",
azure_endpoint = "xxx"

)

OK, without extra body part, with only response_message = response.choices[0].message
messages.append(response_message)
and get data and insert:
messages.append({
"tool_call_id": call_id,
"role": "tool",
"name": "getWeather",
"content": json.dumps(odptext),
})
works,
with extra body i have error 400
